# Can't install software to Program files after hardware replacement

Tags: windows-10

Bought new PC parts (CPU and motherboard). And booted Widows 10 which was already installed on my SSD.
To my surprise it booted.

Then I wanted to install some drivers with MSI Live Update tool, but unfortunately I couldn't install anything to Program Files\Program Data folders. Installers (I tried Intel VGA driver or live update tool for example) say: 
Access denied.
Launching installers with admin rights has no effect.

Are there any recipe to quick fix access rights after hardware replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it while writing this question. Right-clicked hard-drive->Properties->Tools->Error checking. Analysis said that problems not found, but after that I managed to install required software (even did not make a reboot).